# Label cuts-off at the end of the client's rectangle

Tags: c#

*This currently goes for WPF, but I need an answer for WinForms aswell, if possible.*

I made a user-control that contains a .NET's Label.

The issue is:
When the label is long enough, it passes the end of the user-control's size which isn't elegant and can mistake the user to think that the string ends.

What I want to do about it, but don't know how:

Check where the label is getting cut-off from the client's size, then replace the 3 last characters from there with 3 dots "...". (so the user could know that the string didn't end, etc.)

Any suggestions? (just in case: I don't mind making my own user control just for the label).
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Winforms: Set the AutoSize property on the label to false and the AutoElipses property to true.

In WPF, you can set the content to a TextBlock with the TextTrimming property set:

```
<Label Height="29"  Width="35" >
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">This is a really long string</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Comment: Why bother with a `Label` just use a `TextBlock` directly

Comment: @MarkHall True.  There may be a reason in the OPs situation that requires a label, but I agree that a TextBlock alone would work.

Comment: To be honest, I was surprised those properties were there all along. Thank you very much, my problem is solved.